# Can a On-Premises application use Microsoft Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus

My application uses **On Premises Service Bus**. How can I migrate my application to use **Azure Service bus**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you embark on the journey of migrating to Azure Service Bus I would highly advise reviewing the differences between Service Bus for Windows Server (or SBWS) product (retired) and Azure Service Bus (ASB). While they used to have a common starting point, over they became two completely different products. SBWS was an on-premises, SQL Server backed offer. ASB is a hosted service running in Azure with two very distinct tiers, Standard and Premium. Behaviour wise the SBWS and ASB will work differently just because you will have a network between your system and ASB service.

So the short answer to the question, yes, an on-premises application can use ASB. Can it remain unchanged if it was using SBWS? Unlikely. API surface has changed, some concepts have evolved, etc. Best bet is to review ASB [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/) first and have a proof of concept to verify your scenarios are explored.